# How to use filters on JavaScript array?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.7.1

I am trying to optimize some jQuery and need a little help.  I have some text that appear in divs with the class of Header, like this:

```
<div class='Header'>Some Text</div>
<div class='Header'>More Text</div>
<div class='Header'>Even More</div>
```

Normally, I would do this to slide up every div except for the first one.  Later, I would do something similar and have to use jQuery to find the divs again, which is what I am trying to avoid.

```
// CLOSE ALL EXCEPT THE FIRST
$(".Header:not(:first)").slideUp();
```

So, I know I want to put my divs with the Header class into an object like this:

```
var $HeaderArray = $(".Header);
```

Now I want to perform functions on them, but I can't figure out how to access them the same way that I did previously, using the filters, not and first.  What I want to do is something like this:

```
$HeaderArray:not:first.slideUp();
```

This doesn't work. What is the right way to use filters to get at the right divs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.not` is a function, you need to call it, like so:

```
$HeaderArray.not(':first').slideUp();
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try using [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function,

```
$HeaderArray.not(':first').slideUp();
```